# Using Index( match( max( countifs and it's returning wrong value after first answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm writing a formula to look through a table of data and find the email address that has the max count according to data entered into the formula. I have it written out and working, but after the first answer it keeps returning the same wrong answer even with blank cells, which is making think it is an error. I have used **ctrl+shift+enter** to get it to run as an array.

[image: screen grab with the formula and results]
[image: sample of full data list showing columns]

I've looked through the code when I drag it down to rows below and I have verified that it is looking for the correct input cells in the formula. Some of the emails may have two or more that are max with the max being  or 3. I'll cross that bridge later, but for now the inputs that I know have a definitive max are not outputting correctly either.

> =INDEX('[Load List Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$7454,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS('[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$7454,'[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$7454,'[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$7454,E3,'[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$I$1:$I$7454,G3)),COUNTIFS('[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$7454,'[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$7454,'[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$7454,E3,'[Load List
>   Reference.xlsx]Sheet1'!$I$1:$I$7454,G3)))

I need it to return the correct email address associated with the max number of times it appears in the data. It is showing correctly for the first row, but after that it is outputting the last email address from the list. When there isn't even any data in the search columns it is still outputting that email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, the following example contains the data and results on the same sheet.  You'll need to change the ranges accordingly.  Let's assume that you have the following set-up in `A1:I15`...

[image: A1:I15]

Enter the following formulas...

G2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$15="y",IF($C$2:$C$15="z",IF($A$2:$A$15<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$15,$A$2:$A$15,0)))),ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$2)+1))
```

H2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$15="y",IF($C$2:$C$15="z",IF($A$2:$A$15<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$15,$A$2:$A$15,0)))),ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$2)+1)=G2,1))
```

I2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down...

```
=IF(ROWS(I$2:I2)<=$H$2,INDEX($A$2:$A$15,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$15="y",IF($C$2:$C$15="z",IF($A$2:$A$15<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$15,$A$2:$A$15,0)))),ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$2)+1)=$G$2,ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(I$2:I2))),"")
```

Here are the results...

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you Domenic! It looks like this would definitely work for what I am trying to do, but it won't run on my work computer. Excel is letting me know that it is running out of resources to make this happen. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: Domenic this worked perfectly after I used $ to keep the input static. How do I give you credit for the fix?

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working for you.  You can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark next to my answer.  Cheers!